# Blogger Sticky Post-By-Email

Tags: blogger, sticky

I'm trying to find a way for users of my Blogger page to post to the page by email, but to have these posts-by-email appear as stickied posts (or similar).

I get that post-by-email works by emailing username.secretword@blogger.com, but does anyone know if there are any other options that can be added to the email to allow some added control? The post-by-email method allows you to cut off extra text in your email that you don't want to appear in the post (like an email sig) by using the keyword #end. Are there any other keywords that anyone knows?

I also understand that you can use a [method of altering the date](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Sticky-Post-in-Blogger) to make a post a sticky once it has been published. So I'm hoping that there's a way of sending this altered date data in the post-by-email email. Maybe with some other keyword like #date?

Alternatively, is there a way of using post-by-email to create gadgets that appear on the template--ie to create a post in a sidebar via post-by-email?

In short--some way of using post-by-email to create a post that stays visible on a Blogger page. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.